# How to avoid duplicated registration securely by people who already registered personally?

Tags: security, registration

We got personal registrations with name, birth date, address from the last 30 years and we have an online system. We want to avoid duplicated registration, since the history of these people is very important from business perspective. Currently by online registration giving the name and birth date is enough to the system to find the personally registered account and let the user set the username, phone number, email address and password. From security perspective this is a huge problem, since everybody can take these accounts by knowing the name and the birth date. Is there a better solution, how to make this system safer?

Comment: Wait, so you're saying with a name and birth date, I could completely hijack an account?

My solution would be to not do that.

At least send them a confirmation e-mail, I'd say.

Comment: @DrSatan1 A confirmation email to where?

Comment: If you don't have a usable e-mail address for these people, and it's unacceptable that some accounts might be lost, then probably your only solution will be a real-life "check ID/call customer, change details" type situation.

Comment: @DrSatan1 It would be nice, but we don't have phone numbers, and there is no guarantee that the mailing address is the same after a few decades. There is no guarantee that these people will show up in the next few years either but if they do, their history will be important by discounts.

Comment: `"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."` - You sure you read that part? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call these accounts "online" and "offline". I have come up with the following system:

- The online and offline accounts are different entities, since the online accounts are identified by username and password, while the offline accounts are currently identified by name and birth date.
- There is no 1:1 relation between online and offline accounts, since the names can change. So there is 1:n relation between them.
- Customers can attach an offline account to an online account by starting an activation process. Without attaching the accounts, they won't get discounts based on the offline history.
- If customers want to do anything personally, they'll need an online account hereafter. If they don't have one, they have to ask an administrator to create one. By creating such an online account personally the administrator should ask whether they have any offline account, so the activation process can be started.
- In the activation process the customer must give the identifiers of the online account and the identifiers of the offline account to the administrator. We can use extra verification, for example asking about the offline history, etc... The system should verify whether these accounts are really compatible, e.g. by comparing the birth dates.
- On long run we have to get rid of offline accounts and merge their history with the online accounts. So we need a deadline e.g. a few years, and after that deadline we should delete every non-merged offline account and simplify the system.